# Shiny R reactivevalues memory leak

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm trying to understand why a cycling use of shiny's `reactivevalues` causes it to use more memory. The context is a user interface with the option to automate a given strategy. The example below is based on the St. Petersburg paradox. I appreciate that it may be better practice to place the entire automation process in a seperate function file but I would like to understand why the reactive object increases in size and if there is a more immediate work around.

The example below will print out the amount of memory `values` is using on the disk. There is no increase in size to the list saved to it.

```
library(shiny)
library(pryr)


server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  values=reactiveValues(win=0,
                        total=1000,
                        gamble=0,
                        stick=0,
                        outcome=0,
                        auto.counter=0
                        )


  #############################################
  # update action from buttons
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$stick)){
      isolate({
      values$stick=values$stick+1
      })
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$gamble)){
      isolate({
        values$gamble=values$gamble+1
      })
    }
  })

  #############################################
  ## perform stick action
  observe({
    if(values$stick>0){
      isolate({
        values$total=values$total+2^values$win
        values$auto.counter=max(values$auto.counter-1,0)
        values$win=0
        cat("\nStick:",2^values$win)
        cat("\nReactive values size:",object_size(values))
      })
    }
  })
  # perform gamble action
  observe({
    if(values$gamble>0){
    isolate({
      values$outcome=sample(1:2,1)
      if(values$win==0){
        values$total=values$total-input$entry
      }
      if(values$outcome==1){
        output$print=renderText("Win")
        values$win=values$win+1
      } else {
        output$print=renderText("Lose")
        values$win=0
      }
      cat("\nGamble:",2^values$win)
      cat("\nReactive values size:",object_size(values))
      values$auto.counter=max(values$auto.counter-1,0)

    })
    }
  })

  #############################################
  # automation input
  observe({
    if(input$automate>0){
      isolate({
        values$auto.counter=input$rep
      })
    }
  })

  # if automation on run until auto.counter==0
  observe({
    if(!is.null(values$auto.counter)){
      if(values$auto.counter>0){
        isolate({
          if(2^values$win>input$target){
            values$stick=values$stick+1
          } else {
            values$gamble=values$gamble+1
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
  #############################################
  # render views
  output$total=renderText({paste("Total winnings:",values$total)})
  output$currentvalue=renderText({paste("Current jackpot:",2^values$win)})
})


ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(

  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      4,
      numericInput(inputId="entry",label="Entry Fee",value=10),
      actionButton(inputId="gamble",label='Gamble'),
      actionButton(inputId="stick",label='Stick'),
      h4("Automate"),
      numericInput(inputId="target",label="Target value",value=20),
      numericInput(inputId="rep",label="Turns",value=10),
      actionButton(inputId="automate",label='Automate')
    ),
    column(
      8,
      textOutput("currentvalue"),
      textOutput("total"),
      textOutput("print")
      )
  )
))


runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: This discussion seems relevant, but seems unresolved as of now: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/O6cDt3Mz9Qk